# Component whose children can fill it

Tags: css, reactjs

I marked this question with "react" tag, however, I think that framework does not matter so much in this case.

I have a component, whose job is to display some children. All this component does is it displays some styling - a border and a background - so it's just a box.

This box could be displayed "dynamically", so no static height would be specified - it could be "flex-grow: 1" for example.

How to make the children fill this component entirely?

This is my Box:

```
class Box extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={"box " + this.props.className}>
        <h2>BOX</h2>
        <div>{this.props.children}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here are its styles:

```
.box {
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

Ideally, child would just set "height: 100%", but this will not work, because Box does not define any height.

One solution would be to set "display:flex" on the div inside of which "{this.props.children}" is placed. However, this requires children to use "flex-grow: 1" - I think it's not best solution, because children shouldn't know how Box is implemented. It also makes the problem recursive - children of my children again need to use flex-grow...

//EDIT
Here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-sunset-bvhjh

Box-content should fill the whole place that it has in a Box, but it does not. How to achieve that?

Comment: could you add a codesandbox to help understanding the issue ?

Comment: @GaëlS I provided an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that in pure css (this way, children do not need to be aware of the `flex` mode of their parents) :

```
.row2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row2 > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

by styling all the child `div`s.

a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-lalande-kor03) to see the result